# nginx 413 Request Entity Too Large(client intended to send too large body)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I know that this question has been asked multiple times but I have tried all of them and updated `client_max_body_size` to `0` and to even `16400M` but it didn't help. I did asked my hosting support to restart the nginx and php fpm service too.

My server configuration is:

2GB RAM, 
Plesk server version : Plesk 12.5.30
Wordpress version : 4.6.1
PHP versoin : 7.0.12 set to run php at `fastCGI application served by apache`

The website is in wordpress and I can't even upload a file larger then 100mb from wordpress media uploader or through any other form.

From media uploader it gives this error in the ajax post request :
`POST https://transcriptionpanda.com/wp-admin/async-upload.php`

In my server logs I see this nginx error :
`15271#0: *307 client intended to send too large body: 710634025 bytes`

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` code is :

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
client_max_body_size 0;
client_header_buffer_size 4k;
large_client_header_buffers  4 4k;
client_body_buffer_size  256k;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

I am really hopeless now and not sure what to do. Smaller file uploads fine(100MB or so). Files larger then 100MB fails to upload.

Any help would be appreciated.

> **Update**:
>   Here is a link of phpinfo of website server:
>   https://transcriptionpanda.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following configurations -

**Nginx**

```
client_max_body_size
```

**PHP**

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
```

And restart.

Source:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size
- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: I have already checked those settings and restarted services. Still not working

Comment: Have you checked Apache's `LimitRequestBody` ?

Comment: where can I check that @tan

Comment: I don't use Plesk. I'm guessing it's under /etc/apache2/ ?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: thanks for `LimitRequestBody`. I asked my hosting to check this and update and restart accordingly and they then said they faced this issue in nginx which is a known bug which prevented them from updating and thus they need to reconfigure/reinstall nginx.